# Open screen on login - react native

Tags: react-native

I have a function that shows me an alert when the username and password are correct, but I want to send me a screen as soon as the username and password are correct, I have tried but I have not been able to do it.

in my attempts I have another validation which is if I log in but it does not validate, it is only verifying that the route exists but so put the password or the wrong email log in, I need it to validate and if the user and password are correct there yes let me log in.

```js
const signIn = async({correo, password}: LoginData) => {
       
        try {

         await fetch('https://www.portal.multigobernanza.com/apiMultigobernanza/usuarios/login.php',
            {
              method:'POST',
              headers:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'content-Type': 'application/json'
         
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({"email":correo, "password" : password})
            }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(resData => {
             Alert.alert(resData.message)
             console.log(resData);
           
            });
            
           }catch (error) {
            dispatch({type: 'addError',
            payload: error.response.data.msg || 'Información incorrecta'})
           }
    };
```

other validation

```js
const signIn = async({correo, password}: LoginData) => {
       
        try {

const {data} = await cafeApi.post<LoginResponse>('/usuarios/login.php',{correo,password});
          dispatch({
              type: 'signUp',
              payload: {
                  token: data.token,
                  user: data.usuario
              }
          });

          await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
          
        } catch (error) {
          dispatch({type: 'addError',
                     payload: error.response.data.msg || 'Información incorrecta'})
        }
};
```

GIT

https://github.com/Giovannychvz/react-native

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how react-navigation suggest [authentication flows](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/). To achieve something like that, at the very least you will need a state variable that keeps track of when a user is signed in, and to modify your signIn function to update your state variable

Comment: But if I already had it, how would I get it to redirect me to the route and not show me an alert?

Comment: Could you link the code  with your screens?

Comment: I already added the complete code, the idea is that when I log in it sends me to "ProtectedScreen"

Comment: I've been looking at your code and I managed to make it to the `ProtectedScreen.tsx`. I think the issue is in your TextInputs on `RegisterScreen.tsx`. Currently your TextInputs call `onRegister` when onSubmitEditing is fired. The button un-intuitively  redirects to another page. I think the submit button should call `onRegister` and the TextInputs should use `onChange`.

Comment: Also you may want to consider using `navigation.push` instead of `navigation.replace`. To go back a screen you would no longer have to hard  code  the destination and could simply use `navigation.goBack()`, which may make its easier to simply have a back button component

Comment: Ok, but in the case where I verify the session, how do I make it send me to browse and not to the alert?, that I need some screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245060/discussion-between-phantomspooks-and-giovanny).